# Regular Expression - Retrieve specific asterisk separated value string

Tags: sql, regex, oracle

I need to retrieve a specific part of a string which has values separated by asterisk's

In the example below I need to retrieve the string **Client Contact Centre Seniors2** which sits between the 6 and 7 asterisk.

I am fairly new to regular expressions and have only managed to find select a value between 2 asterisks using *[\w]+*

Is there a way to specify which number of asterisk to look at using regular expression, or is there a better way for me to retrieve the string I am after?

String:
**2*J25*Owner11*Owner Group2*L231*CLIENTCONTACTCENTRESENIORSQUEUE29*Client Contact Centre Seniors2*K20*0*2*C110*SR_STAT_ID2*N18*Referred2*O10***

Note: I will be using this regular expression in Oracle SQL using `REGEXP_LIKE(string, regex)`.

Comment: In a moderately powerful regex language, you could use a notation such as `^([^*]*\*){6}([^*]*)\*` where the first parenthesized expression matches 6 units of 'zero or more non-asterisks followed by an asterisk' and the second matches 'zero or more non-asterisks' and the final `\*` matches the seventh asterisk.  You will have to tune that to the regex language that Oracle actually supports.  I've not looked to see which regex-variant it uses.

Comment: Thank you Jonathan, I used the following in oracle which returns the second capturing group from the expression you provided regexp_substr(Audits.audit_log, '^([^*]*\*){6}([^*]*)',1,1,null,2)

Your right sam, I am using regexp_substr() to return the string

Answer (score 0):

`*` is a regex operator and needs to be escaped, unless used inside brackets that holds character list. You can use this simplified pattern to extract the
seventh word.

```
regexp_substr(Audits.audit_log,'[^*]+',1,7)
```

[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/d41d8/36646)

**Query 1**:

```
with x(y) as (
  select '2*J25*Owner11*Owner Group2*L231*CLIENTCONTACTCENTRESENIORSQUEUE29*Client Contact Centre Seniors2*K20*0*2*C110*SR_STAT_ID2*N18*Referred2*O10*'
  from dual
  )
select regexp_substr(y,'([^*]+)\*',1,7,null,1)
from x
```

**[Results](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/d41d8/36646/0)**:

```
| REGEXP_SUBSTR(Y,'([^*]+)\*',1,7,NULL,1) |
|-----------------------------------------|
|          Client Contact Centre Seniors2 |
```

**Query 2**:

```
with x(y) as (
  select '2*J25*Owner11*Owner Group2*L231*CLIENTCONTACTCENTRESENIORSQUEUE29*Client Contact Centre Seniors2*K20*0*2*C110*SR_STAT_ID2*N18*Referred2*O10*'
  from dual
  )
select regexp_substr(y,'[^*]+',1,7)
from x
```

**[Results](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/d41d8/36646/1)**:

```
|   REGEXP_SUBSTR(Y,'[^*]+',1,7) |
|--------------------------------|
| Client Contact Centre Seniors2 |
```

Answer (score 0):

You could also use `INSTR` and `SUBSTR` for that. Simple and fast, but not as concise as the `REGEXP_SUBSTR`.

```
with t as (   
  select '2*J25*Owner11*Owner Group2*L231*CLIENTCONTACTCENTRESENIORSQUEUE29*Client Contact Centre Seniors2*K20*0*2*C110*SR_STAT_ID2*N18*Referred2*O10*' testvalue
  from dual
)
select substr(testvalue, instr(testvalue, '*', 1, 6)+1, instr(testvalue, '*', 1, 7) - instr(testvalue, '*', 1, 6) - 1)
from t;
```